# How to pass object between Android activities during back navigation

Tags: android-activity, navigation, back, savestate

In my Android app I have two activities: Activity A and Activity B. The first one (A) starts the second one (B) with `startActivity()`.

If the user hits the back button, I'd like Activity B to pass an object back to Activity A before it's destroyed. The only thing I can come up with is to override `onBackPressed()` in Activity B and save the object in `SharedPreferences`, then retrieve the object from `SharedPreferences` in Activity A's `onResume()`. Can anyone recommend a more elegant solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solutions to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Nitish I ended up setting this property in the AndroidManifest: `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for Activity A, so that it's not reinitialized and retains the member object I was trying to pass from Activity B when "back" is hit. Because Activity A doesn't go through the entire activity lifecycle when going back, its members are intact. This wouldn't work if you wanted to say modify the object in Activity B and port the changes back to A, but I didn't need that. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I ended up overriding `onBackPressed()` and using `startActivityForResult()`